# Problems with autoload wordpress plugin development

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, autoload

My autoload is not working in wordpress (It's Not including the files), What can the problem be ?
If you read my comments you will understand it i think.

I am already trying the hole day to fix this problem. So if somebody knows the solution i really want to hear it : )

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test Autoload
Plugin URI:  http://autoload.com
Description: Test Autoload
Version:     1.0
*/

if(!class_exists('Test_Autoload')) {

    final class Test_Autoload {

    public function __construct() {
            Test_Autoload::register();
        }

        /**
         * Registers Test_Autoload Loader as an SPL autoloader.
         *
         * @param boolean $prepend
         */
        public static function register($prepend = false)
        {
            if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '>=')) {
                spl_autoload_register(array(new self, 'autoload'), true, $prepend);
            } else {
                spl_autoload_register(array(new self, 'autoload'));
            }
        }

        /**
         * Handles autoloading of Test_Autoload classes.
         *
         * @param string $class
         */
        public static function autoload($class)
        {

            $class = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'admin/classes/' . $class .'.php';


            // If the specified $class does not include our namespace return

            if ( false === strpos( $class, 'Test_Autoload' ) ) {
            return;
            }

            if (is_file($class)) {
                require_once($class);
            } else {
                wp_die("The file attempting to be loaded at $class does not exist.");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

---

Comment: When you say "not working," what do you mean? Please be more specific

Comment: It's not including the classes

Answer (score 0):

A simple and functionnal class to autoload with or withour namespaces 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/lalainarahajason/wordpress-autoloader)